Integral of Dirac delta function - variable of integration is a function
There are quite a few properties of the Dirac delta function, but I can't seem to use them to figure out a simplification for the following integral:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-s)df(t)$
Intuition (which very well could be wrong) wants to tell me it's $df(s)$.
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t-s)df(t) = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \int_{s - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon}^{s + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon} \frac{1}{\epsilon} df(t) \\ = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}  \frac{1}{\epsilon} [f(s + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon) - f(s - \frac{1}{2}\epsilon)] \\
= f'(s)$
Not quite what I expected...

For many nice functions you have $\int g(t) df(t) = \int g(t) f'(t) dt$, so this might give you some intuition
